# How do I pass an NLog logger as optional parameter

Tags: vb.net, nlog

I'm working with code that references a library that has an optional NLog.Logger as a parameter (the code for this library with this method definition was lost so I have to recreate it). The code below complains with this message: "Error   41  Constant expression is required." I can't figure out how to make this work though as I've tried to define a Const, as well as just setting the default value to null and nothing works. How do I create an option parameter of type Logger? Thanks!

```
Dim objTraceLogDefault As Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("TraceFile")

Public Function MyFunction(Optional ByVal objTraceLog As Logger = 
objTraceLogDefault)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional parameters should be constants, (e.g. numbers, strings or `Nothing`), because the compiler add the constant values add compile time.

You could set the default to `Nothing` and check for `Nothing` in the body.

```
Private Function MyFunction(ByVal Optional objTraceLog As Logger = Nothing)
    objTraceLog = If(objTraceLog, objTraceLogDefault)
End Function
```

Comment: I haven't done VB in years, "Nothing" was was I was looking for!!! Thanks so much!